# Node.js profiling with Dtrace not showing functions names

Tags: node.js, profiling, dtrace, opensolaris

I'm trying to profile CPU utilization for my [project](https://github.com/dalssoft/memcached.js) using DTrace. I just followed the [script](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/)

The problem is that it doesn't show the functions names. The `stacks.out` file looks like that:

```
 CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
   0  73700                        :tick-60s 


          node`_ZN2v86Object3GetENS_6HandleINS_5ValueEEE+0x1
          node`_ZN4node7TCPWrap12OnConnectionEP11uv_stream_si+0x14b
          node`uv__server_io+0xbf
          node`uv__io_poll+0x259
          node`uv_run+0xda
          node`_ZN4node5StartEiPPc+0x16d
          node`main+0x1b
          node`_start+0x83
            1

          node`_ZN4node6Buffer4FillERKN2v89ArgumentsE+0x22b
          0x82474d1b
          0x8241ee9c
          0x8241e624
          0x8241e30f
          0x82426abd
          0x82419e4e
          0x82419948
          0x82413fc3
          0x8d20e501
          0x82416f65
          0x82413f98
          0x8243e7d3
          0x824186c0
          0x8246e8cf
          0x8d221899
          0x8d21308a
          node`_ZN2v88internalL6InvokeEbNS0_6HandleINS0_10JSFunctionEEENS1_INS0_6ObjectEEEiPS5_Pb+0x101
          node`_ZN2v88internal9Execution4CallENS0_6HandleINS0_6ObjectEEES4_iPS4_Pbb+0xc9
          node`_ZN2v88Function4CallENS_6HandleINS_6ObjectEEEiPNS1_INS_5ValueEEE+0x10b
          node`_ZN4node12MakeCallbackEN2v86HandleINS0_6ObjectEEENS1_INS0_8FunctionEEEiPNS1_INS0_5ValueEEE+0x4c
          node`_ZN4node12MakeCallbackEN2v86HandleINS0_6ObjectEEENS1_INS0_6StringEEEiPNS1_INS0_5ValueEEE+0x66
          node`_ZN4node10StreamWrap12OnReadCommonEP11uv_stream_si8uv_buf_t14uv_handle_type+0x14f
          node`_ZN4node10StreamWrap6OnReadEP11uv_stream_si8uv_buf_t+0x2e
          node`uv__read+0x281
          node`uv__stream_io+0x131
          node`uv__io_poll+0x259
          node`uv_run+0xda
          node`_ZN4node5StartEiPPc+0x16d
          node`main+0x1b
          node`_start+0x83
            1
```

The flame graph shows hex (ie. "0x82474d1b") as functions calls and not the actual function name.

I'm using OmniOS (illumos based OS) vagrant box [r151002](http://www.vagrantbox.es) and did this (https://gist.github.com/dalssoft/5595688) to build node.js 32bits on OmniOS.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issues when writing my blog post about using openindiana and node.js together.

http://blog.nearform.com/blog/node-openindiana.html

I found being explicit with the cpu arch was the way to resolve it.

```
./configure --with-dtrace --dest-cpu=x64
```

Don't forget to demangle the c++ symbols too

```
c++filt < stacks.out > demangled.out
```

Comment: cool! gonna try it and then I tell you if it worked on OmniOS :)

Comment: For future reference, the aforementioned blog post seems to have been moved here: http://www.nearform.com/nodecrunch/node-openindiana

Comment: Moved again. Reference to archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20130717020412/http://blog.nearform.com/blog/node-openindiana.html

Comment: Put it on my own site too http://venshare.com/2014/09/21/node-js-on-open-indiana/ Thanks for the bump