# No function names when using DTrace on Node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling, dtrace, omnios

I am trying to use DTrace for CPU profiling of a Node.js program according to [this guide](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/) on an OmniOS VM in VirtualBox, which I set up following [these steps](https://gist.github.com/dalssoft/5595688) exactly (except for using node 0.10.26).

Unfortunately, DTrace does not give me human-readable JS function names, but just the raw function addresses (as far as I understand), which looks like this and is not very helpful:

```
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  0  66407                        :tick-30s 


              node`v8::internal::String::ComputeHashField(unibrow::CharacterStream*, int, unsigned int)+0x162
              node`v8::internal::Utf8SymbolKey::Hash() [clone .part.342]+0xb9
              node`v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::SymbolTableShape, v8::internal::HashTableKey*>::FindEntry(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::HashTableKey*)+0x20
              node`v8::internal::SymbolTable::LookupKey(v8::internal::HashTableKey*, v8::internal::Object**)+0x38
              node`v8::internal::SymbolTable::LookupSymbol(v8::internal::Vector<char const>, v8::internal::Object**)+0x4e
              node`v8::internal::Heap::LookupSymbol(v8::internal::Vector<char const>)+0x34
              node`v8::internal::Factory::LookupSymbol(v8::internal::Vector<char const>)+0x34
              node`v8::internal::JSProxy::CallTrap(char const*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*)+0x76
              node`v8::internal::JSProxy::GetPropertyWithHandler(v8::internal::Object*, v8::internal::String*)+0x108
              node`v8::internal::Object::GetProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::LookupResult*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, PropertyAttributes*)+0x57
              node`v8::internal::LoadIC::Load(v8::internal::InlineCacheState, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>)+0x49d
              node`v8::internal::LoadIC_Miss(v8::internal::Arguments, v8::internal::Isolate*)+0xbd
              0xa730a376
              0x8966eee0
              0x8968bb7c
              0xa7321899
              0xa731308a
```

The above is the result of running these commands:

```
dtrace -n 'profile-97/pid == 12345 && arg1/{ @[jstack(150, 8000)] = count(); } tick-30s { exit(0); }' > stacks.out
gc++filt < stacks.out > demangled.out
```

I have no prior experience with DTrace, but from what have I gathered so far, Node's [ustack helper](https://www.joyent.com/blog/understanding-dtrace-ustack-helpers) should translate these addresses into readable names. This functionality should be enabled when building Node with the `--with-dtrace` flag (which I did), but apparently it is not working for me.

Pretty much the exact same question has actually been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616373), but the accepted answer there did not help in my case, as I was using `--dest-cpu=x64` anyway (also tried `--dest-cpu=ia32` just to be sure, but that did not make any difference).

Comment: Can you also post the dtrace command you are running?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat Sure, added the commands to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks to this excellent post about [node.js+DTrace on FreeBSD](https://blog.indutny.com/7.freebsd-dtrace). Starting Node with the `DTRACE_DOF_INIT_DEBUG` flag resulted in a message suspiciously similar to the one mentioned in the article:

```
dtrace DOF: DTrace ioctl failed for DOF at cd5240 in /usr/local/bin/node: Arg list too long
dtrace DOF: DTrace ioctl succeeded for DOF at 1397e70 in /usr/local/bin/node
```

Even though the article is about FreeBSD, the relevant part of the DTrace source (`dtrace_dof_copyin` in `dtrace.c`) is almost identical (see [FreeBSD source](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/3ecc6f129801776dd571d69cf9a262a97ad23968/sys/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/uts/common/dtrace/dtrace.c#L11989) vs. [OmniOS source](https://github.com/omniti-labs/illumos-omnios/blob/master/usr/src/uts/common/dtrace/dtrace.c#L12284)). Hence, it looked like in my case, the Node ustack helper was also exceeding the size limit for DOFs/DTrace objects, even though that limit is set to [8 mb](https://github.com/omniti-labs/illumos-omnios/blob/master/usr/src/uts/common/dtrace/dtrace.c#L120) in OmniOS, as opposed to [256 kb](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/3ecc6f129801776dd571d69cf9a262a97ad23968/sys/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/uts/common/dtrace/dtrace.c#L158) in FreeBSD.

To verify the assumption, I tried the exact same procedure with Node v0.10.5 instead of v0.10.26, since that was the version that had apparently worked for at least [3 people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616373) before, and it also did trick in my case; starting Node with the aforementioned flag prints:

```
dtrace DOF: DTrace ioctl succeeded for DOF at cd6c88 in /usr/local/bin/node
dtrace DOF: DTrace ioctl succeeded for DOF at d122c8 in /usr/local/bin/node
```

And JS function names are appearing in DTrace output as expected.

**EDIT**: Node v0.10.20 is the most recent version where it works.